# Is there an alternative to char for storing one byte numeric values?

Tags: c++

A `char` stores a numeric value from 0 to 255. But there seems to also be an implication that this type should be printed as a letter rather than a number by default.

This code produces 22:

```
int Bits = 0xE250;
signed int Test = ((Bits & 0x3F00) >> 8);
std::cout << "Test: " << Test <<std::endl; // 22
```

But I don't need `Test` to be 4 bytes long. One byte is enough. But if I do this:

```
int Bits = 0xE250;
signed char Test = ((Bits & 0x3F00) >> 8);
std::cout << "Test: " << Test <<std::endl; // "
```

I get `"` (a double quote symbol). Because `char` doesn't just make it an 8 bit variable, it also says, "this number represents a character".

Is there some way to specify a variable that is 8 bits long, like `char`, but also says, "this is meant as a number"?

I know I can cast or convert `char`, but I'd like to just use a number type to begin with. It there a better choice? Is it better to use `short int` even though it's twice the size needed?

Comment: No, all the 8-bit types even `int8_t` get printed as characters, on Windows even some 16-bit types are, you just have to cast to `int` before printing

Comment: I would say `std::byte` but apparently it cannot be printed via `std::cout`.

Comment: @Quimby nice idea, he  could provide respective overload of `operator<<`.

Comment: @MarekR I am not sure that is allowed with only `std::` arguments, it certainly cannot be put into `std` namespace.

Comment: "Because char doesn't just make it an 8 bit variable, it also says, 'this number represents a character'." No, it does not, because such numbers don't represent characters, because they can't. The name is a historical accident, a holdover from when we deluded ourselves to the contrary.

Comment: That said, if you are trying to save a single byte on a modern system - with gigabytes of memory *and 64-bit registers* - it is extremely unlikely that you will actually accomplish anything.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I'm building libraries that will also run on ARM32 micro controllers.

Answer (score 1):

cast your **character** variable to **int** before printing

```
signed char Test = ((Bits & 0x3F00) >> 8);
std::cout << "Test: " <<(int) Test <<std::endl;
```

Comment: `std::cout << "Test: " << +Test <<std::endl;`

Comment: But OP said that they don't want to do it.

Comment: It's not that I don't want to cast, it's that I wanted to know if there was a better type for 8 bit numbers because of the implication that `char` represents a letter. Or if it was standard practice to use `char` and always cast when displaying it.

Comment: If you cast to an `int` in `cout`, does it then occupy 32 bits of memory because it is now an `int` type?

Comment: @Nick it's very possible that the casted `int` will be stored in a register meaning it may not occupy memory.

Comment: @Nick at worst it'll be stored on the stack for the duration of the function call, in reality the function will probably be inlined and the cast will be optimised away, e.g. these code snippets produce near identical assembly: https://godbolt.org/z/GeTGKnMcY